# IIS 7.5 Redirect only one subdirectory

Tags: iis-7, http-redirect

I have an asp.net application deployed under IIS 7.5 Version with several sub domains under it. I would like to redirect a particaular subdomain to another url.

For example:

```
www.domain1.com/a
www.domain1.com/b
```

The above urls should work fine.

```
www.domain1.com/c
```

should be redirected to `www.domain2.com`

How can i achieve this?

Update on my requirement: I have same application deployed for several users (a, b, c) with same application pool. I would like to have redirect for only user c.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how IIS manager is configured for your `www.domain1.com`? Something on the lines of http://i.stack.imgur.com/s9UoA.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using rewrite module.
I have updated web.config as follows :

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<clear />
    <rule name="Redirect For c" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^c$" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^c/$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain2.com" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the IIS manager. Open the Run dialog (*Windows+R*), type `inetmgr` and press `Enter`. You will need Adminstrator privileges for this.
2. Select the sub-folder (**not virtual folder**) within your website in the left pane (by clicking on the folder name) and then open `HTTP Redirect` in the main view.
   [image: Sub-folder selection and HTTP Redirect icon]
3. Select `Redirect requests to this destination` and type in your destination domain name `http://www.domain2.com/`. Check the other options (if they are applicable to you) and click `Apply` to save.
   [image: Setup redirection for sub-folder]
4. Check the redirection in your browser.

Comment: I tried the above solution but it was redirecting for all sub domains.

Comment: @VVutpala Did you select the sub-directory _first_ before modifying the "HTTP Redirect" settings? This process has been tested. It redirects only for the sub-directory. You have some other configuration parameters that might be overriding it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes. I have updated my question.  "I have same application deployed for several users (a, b, c) with same application pool and same virtual path. I would like to have redirect for only user c".  Can you please suggest solution now?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply redirect to sub folder c because they share a web.config file. When you add this setting via IIS, it adds it to he shared web.config.

Get rid of folder c or rename it. Create a new folder in wwwroot ie "c_redirect". 
In IIS create a new virtual directory with alias "c", and point it to your new empty folder. You can then add a redirect to the site in IIS and it will create a new web.config in the c_redirect folder with your setting, and not affect the parent site.